# ReactiveSwift emit elements from an array with a delay between elements

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

Let's say I have an array of elements `[1, 2, 3]` and a delay of `5` seconds.

I want to emit each element of the array with a pause between the current element emited and the next.

Example:

Output:

```
[00:00] -- 1
[00:05] -- 2
[00:10] -- 3
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
import ReactiveSwift

let startTime     = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
let arrayProperty = MutableProperty<[Int]>([1, 2, 3])
let arraySignal   = arrayProperty.signal
arraySignal
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .delay(2, on: QueueScheduler.main)
    .observeValues { element in
        let elapsed = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
        print("\((elapsed - startTime) / 1_000_000_000) -- \(element)")
    }
```

But it only delays the emission of the first element and emits the next ones immediately.

I couldn't find the proper operator mix to use, maybe they are missing on ReactiveSwift framework, and I'm a beginner in Reactive programming so implementing my own operator is way too hard yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven’t had a chance to try this code, but it should be something like this:

```
SignalProducer([1, 2, 3])
    .flatMap(.concat) { n in
        return SignalProducer(value: n).delay(2, on: QueueScheduler.main)
    }
    .startWithValues { element in
        let elapsed = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
        print("\((elapsed - startTime) / 1_000_000_000) -- \(element)")
    }
```

The key is that you use `flatMap` to create a new signal producer for each value which you can apply the delay to, and combine them with the `.concat` flatten strategy.

(Also, note you can use the signal producer initializer that takes a sequence)